Which movie scene is it where sniper takes a shot through a moving exhaust fan to save a hostage?
I have searched best sniper movie scenes but couldn't find this one. This is an ultimate shot taken by the sniper to save the hostage.
In this movie sniper is sitting pretty far perhaps on roof top and takes the shot in night.
What makes the shot tough is moving blades of the fan, which can stop the bullet. Sniper has to calculate the speed, wind AND timing. Sniper has to pass the bullet from the gap between two adjacent blades.
It was awesome movie scene.
My best guess about scene, it can be little bit here or there:

Scene was shot in summer, because both hostage and hostile were sweating , and were wearing summer clothes like vest etc. (I am sure)
Scene was shot in pale yellow background like dim light yellow bulb. (I am sure)
Sniper was from military. (not 100% sure)
Sniper was blond man (not 100% sure)
Sniper lost had lost reputation in his team, team wasn't sure that his shot would be successful (I am sure)
Hostile knew that there are people outside to kill him so he went deeper in the room.  (How he knew? because one shot from team went in vain). Due to which only one place left to take the shot which was through the fan. (I am sure)
Climax or turning point of entire movie.
Hostage was grabbed from back with neck, both were standing. (I am sure)
Hostage was a lady.(not 100% sure)


I was thinking there was a scene like this in the Angelina Jolie movie Wanted, when James McAvoy's character was in training, but don't remember for sure.

Is it definitely a hostage scene? There is a similar scene in the pilot episode of Alphas but the sniper is a brainwashed assassin.

Give some information about hostage(male/female) and the shooter. Was the shooter military or police? How long was the sniper.

Any idea of the country of origin for the film?  Approximate year of release or year you saw it?  Was it dubbed or subtitled?  Did you see it in theaters or on TV?  Were there any major stars who were in it?

Top notch stars of bratt pitt level werent there. Sniper was blond guy (American looks, also language was american english, not British accent) so I guess it was a hollywood (US) make.

@Fruitbat ... actually, that is what I was thinking of and not Wanted. Good call.

Year of release? Would be helpful. In terms of the shot, do we watch from the sniper's POV (like through the scope or something), do we follow the bullet on it's path through the fan?

I am sorry, I am very bad in guessing year(if I knew wouldnt have posted it here :) ). Yes scene was shot from sniper's POV sniper was looking at the hostile moving here n there, through the gap in b/w fan blades, through the gun mounted binoculars.

Doesn't have to be exact year, even when you saw it can be a good reference- tells us what year to stop looking at, or basic range, so we know not to look at movies that are too old or too new. Generally with Movie ID questions, it's good practice to put at least an estimated release/watch date.

In between 1995-2014, I dont know it would help...

@Paulster2 - There is a similar scene in Wanted (the assassination on the rooftop). "Goodbye, Mr X".

@Paulster2 I think the scene you're trying to remember was James McAvoy's first assignment to kill a person but he hesitates when he has a clear shot thinking the other guy might be a good person but eventually shoots the person by curving the bullet.

@chaitanya89 did bullet went through fan blades?

@paul sorry, I don't know the answer, I was talking about a scene in Wanted movie.

Really does remind me as well of a scene from the pilot of Alphas on SyFy. The "sniper" character was brainwashed into using his "superhuman" ability to make the shot.

can you provide a youtube link

atleast attach a picture. OR the guy who upvoted this answer should do.
